# Cannot get log4j.properties to work with Gradle project in IntelliJ

Tags: java, log4j

I am building a Gradle-based Java project using IntelliJ as my IDE.

I can output log information to my console, as long as it is outputted to INFO.

WARN and ERROR also seems to work by default.

```
...
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
...
public class ServiceExample {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServiceExample.class);
...
        log.info("...");
        log.warn("...");
        log.error("...");
...
```

However I cannot seem to do the same thing for DEBUG.

```
...
        log.debug("...");
...
```

I've created the properties file under:

```
project > src > main > resources > log4j.properties
```

The content is as follows:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

I've tried running my project through bootRun and Debug, and I've also tried cleaning and rebuilding my project, but to no avail.

What do I need to do to get my Java project to show DEBUG in the console?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the application in the debug mode. Because you are using **InteliJ**, you can do so by navigating to the Run section, and the choose the second choice debug. Or the shortcut would be the right top corner little green bug icon. You can find visual representation below.

[image]

Comment: I've tried running the project in debug mode, but the debug logs are still not appearing in the console :( it's almost as if it's been disabled ..

Comment: Change this log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG  to  log4j.rootLogger=info and add this log4j.logger.com.example=debug after all the config in the property file and try it again. @Kurtiss.

ps: Adjust this com.example to appropriate name